# Сортировка массива

Tags: javascript

Какой функцией отсортировать такой массив по фамилиям?

```
var people = [
    { "имя": "Иван", "фамилия": "Иванов" },
    { "имя": "Петр", "фамилия": "Петров" },
    { "имя": "Стас", "фамилия": "Стасов" }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
people.sort(function(a, b){
    return a["фамилия"].charCodeAt(0) - b["фамилия"].charCodeAt(0); 
});
```

Это сортировка по первой букве фамилии. В принципе, можно расписать циклом до конца.
http://javascript.ru/Array/sort